# Limit input size with liferay-ui:input-editor in Liferay

Tags: liferay, overflow, rich-text-editor

I have a question. I have an overflow problem in my database when I input a very long text into the rich editor liferay-ui:input-editor. Is there any method to limit the input size? Thanks.

PD. I have solved provisionally using this tutorial:
[Error messages Liferay tutorial](http://www.liferay.com/es/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/User+Feedback+-+Success+and+Error+Messages+in+Portlets#section-User+Feedback+-+Success+and+Error+Messages+in+Portlets-Adding+your+own+Error+Messages)

Simply check in your portlet:

```
 import com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SessionErrors;
 ...
    private object _updateObject(ActionRequest request) {
    ...
    String nameField1= (ParamUtil.getString(request, "nameField1"));
    ...
    if (nameField1.getBytes().length>bytesfieldindb) {
                SessionErrors.add(request, "error-key");
                return null;
    }
    ...
```

And put in your jsp, in the line where you want to appear the error message:

```
<liferay-ui:error key="error-key" message="message_error WHENEVER YOU WANT" />
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a javascript validator using AlloyUI library.

see `name` filed in this tutorial http://alloyui.com/examples/form-validator/real-world/